# Why two different python environments with sudo?

Tags: python-2.7, package, sudo

Simply, when I type `pip freeze` to show the installed python packages, I see different packages than when I type `sudo pip freeze`.

**Shouldn't they be the same?**

I'm new to this, but from what I read that this may represent two python environments. If so, how can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
which pip
```

and:

```
sudo which pip
```

to find out if you are using the same `pip` command.

Comment: Danke for the answer :) Yes they gave me two different directories: One is `/opt/zld/python/bin/pip` and the other is `usr/local/pip` Can you please tell me how can I make the `sudo pip` as the other `pip`?

Comment: You could play with `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`. But this can cause all kind problems. What is your final goal here, what do you try achieve?